# How to make number auto to step 1, 2, 3 in ListView, Not connection Database

Tags: c#

**Photo Example:**

[image]

*For Form_load Click*

```
private void Form6_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < itm.Length; i++)
            {
                listView1.Columns.Add(itm[i], size[i], HorizontalAlignment.Left);

            }
            listView1.GridLines = true;
            listView1.View = View.Details;
            listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
        }
```

*Code in Button Add_Click*

```
 private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListViewItem data = new ListViewItem();
            data.SubItems.Add(txtname.Text);
            data.SubItems.Add(txtsur.Text);
            data.SubItems.Add(txtage.Text);
            listView1.Items.Add(data);
            clear();
        }
```

Comment: Use `listView1.Items.Count+1` as your index: `data.SubItems.Add(listView1.Items.Count+1)`

Comment: `data.SubItems.Add(listView1.Items.Count+1)` This not work

Comment: Why doesn't work? Please elaborate, i'm not a clairvoyant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `Text` property of new ListViewItem which will be displayed in the first column of the ListView.

```
 private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     ListViewItem data = new ListViewItem();
     data.Text = (listView1.Items.Count + 1).ToString();
     data.SubItems.Add(txtname.Text);
     data.SubItems.Add(txtsur.Text);
     data.SubItems.Add(txtage.Text);
     listView1.Items.Add(data);
     clear();
 }
```

This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes, I want it  Thank Bro :)